# Does any chirality-dependent inorganic chemical reaction exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, chirality

In the particle physics, there are non mirror-symmetric reactions.

In the organic chemistry, particularly in complex proteins, there are reactions producing only a single chirality of molecules.

But what is in the intermediate regime? Does any inorganic chemical reaction exist with an asymmetric chirality behavior?

I suspect, maybe it would be possible with highly asymmetric electron clouds, probably with a significant EM octopole moment.

Comment: Note: as generally in the case of the "does ... exist" questions, giving a "no" answer is harder, but it is still possible.

Comment: I have the impression that my question is probably not very HQ in the grammar/spelling/terminology sense, so any improvements are welcomed.

Comment: Interesting idea! I really can't answer on inorganic chemistry in magnetic fields, but I remember some failed experiments (by a colleague who shall remain unnamed) on asymmetric resolution of organic compounds in an ESR magnet. On the more serious and maybe less related side, there's been a lot of research on photogenerated radical (ion) pairs in magnetic fields.

Comment: Here's a ref: https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/2009/pdf/8101x0019.pdf but as I mentioned, this isn't about inorganic chemistry. You might find it helpful anyway :)

Comment: There are no reactions producing only a single chirality, unless they _start_ from a single chirality. Besides, there are some reactions producing a slight excess of one enantiomer over the other as a result of some asymmetric physical influence (circularly polarized light, etc). Inorganics is no different from organics in this regard.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's why the experiment which I mentioned miserably failed :D Achiral molecules can crystallize in chiral space groups. Sometimes, a reproducible preference for one enatiomer in one lab was observed. The reason typically isn't magnetic magic, but chiral contamination carried in by air.

Comment: @IvanNeretin With organic things I've tried to address the significantly chirality-dependent reactions in the biochemistry. Could you explain, why? I think, some asymmetry could be inserted in the system externally, for example by electric or magnetic field, or by both.

Comment: There are various chiral complexes so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @peterh What's to explain? That's right, some chirality ***must*** be introduced into the system from beyond, otherwise you'll never have any. Chemistry is _perfectly_ symmetric, the way physics was before the discovery of CP violation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's not entirely correct. If you couple spontaneous symmetry breaking and a process that enhances selectivity (e.g., recrystallization), you can achieve enantiomeric naturally, though you can't control which one. So this means that you wouldn't be able to predict the selectivity or reproduce it, but it could occur.

Comment: @Zhe Maybe the direction of the spontaneous symmetry breaking could be controlled by some initiator, for example by an already chiral crystal.

Comment: Yes, that's right; the resulting enantiomer would be determined by pure chance, hence if you run the experiment many times, it would turn out "right" and "left" about equally often. Of course you might use a seed crystal, and probably with great results; that's the mentioned _"chirality from beyond"_.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is that there could be some predictable symmetry breaking element (e.g., polarized light) that initiates a predictable symmetry breaking in a chemical system, but the problem is that this is no longer the realm of chemistry. I think this is also exactly what @IvanNeretin is saying.

Comment: @Zhe I think it could be also a chiral molecule.

Comment: @peterh No because that chiral molecule had to come from some kind of symmetry breaking. You're looking at a chicken-egg situation here.

Comment: See http://oldwww.iucr.org/iucr-top/comm/cteach/pamphlets/21/node7.html and http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja907535g for some near-inorganic examples.

Comment: There are plenty of compounds that on crystallization from a racemic mixture, provide two sets of distinct crystals, with each crystal type being nearly enantiomerically pure.  Of course, there are equal amounts of both crystal types, but I think even a hypothetical non-chiral observer could sort such macroscopic crystals into two separate bins, a la Pasteur and tartaric acid.

Comment: There is a lot of speculation here about complex mechanisms and so on. But doesn't the fact that some inorganic compounds crystallise into single enantiomer, chiral crystals (quartz, for example) basically prove the point? *Inorganic* chirality isn't fundamentally any different to *organic* chirality.

Comment: Maybe the reaction rates between two chiral compounds could also differ if they differ also in their relative chirality. If there is compound1 and compund2, both chiral, then the reaction rate of L-compound1+L-compound2 is the same as R-compound1+R-compound2. But L-compound1+R-compund2 may have a different rate (or even different reactions).

Comment: @matt_black I think it means, yes they exist, but none of them is important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crystalline form of silicon dioxide known as α-quartz is optically active and can spontaneously crystallize in one of the two optically active form. However, which one of the two you get is defined purely by chance.

This, however, is different from "asymmetry" in particle physics, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible answer from inorganic chemistry centered on the $\ce{ClOClO}$ dimer.

Apparently, the $\ce{(ClO)2}$ dimer also exists as $\ce{(OCl)2}$ per the following important reaction leading up to chlorate (problematic from an environmental perspective) formation:

$$\ce{OClOCl + ClOClO -> OClO + Cl2 + OClO}$$

where $\ce{OClO}$ is chlorine dioxide ($\ce{ClO2}$).

**Reference**

1. Kinetics and mechanism of chlorate-chloride reaction by Rafaela T. P. Sant'Anna; Cristina M. P. Santos; Guilherme P. Silva; Ricardo J. R. Ferreira; André P. Oliveira; Carlos E. S. Côrtes; Roberto B. Faria, J. Braz. Chem. Soc. vol.23 no.8 São Paulo **Aug. 2012**  Epub, DOI:[10.1590/S0103-50532012005000017](https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-50532012000800017&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en) ([PDF](https://www.scielo.br/pdf/jbchs/v23n8/aop053_12.pdf))

Comment: Ok, but it seems to me only an isomer. $(ClO)_2$ doesn't even seem to me like a chiral compound.

Comment: More research suggests a characteristic property associated with chiral compounds being a response to "circularly polarized light (CPL) "  (see  http://che.sjtu.edu.cn/EN/Research/tiao_mu/2014/7/31_Construction_and_Mechanism_Research_of_Chiral-Mesoscopic_Inorganic_Materials.html ). The example in that reference uses amino acid doped CuO nano particles.  I believe with that criteria, the list of pure inorganic compounds is limited and includes some esoteric complexes.

Answer (score 1):

Per a source (see http://che.sjtu.edu.cn/EN/Research/tiao_mu/2014/7/31_Construction_and_Mechanism_Research_of_Chiral-Mesoscopic_Inorganic_Materials.html) that appears to directly address the organic/inorganic divide to quote:

"(3) Formation mechanism of chiral inorganic materials

Electronic transition-based optical activity (ETOA) is ubiquitous in organic materials. However, chiral inorganic materials exhibiting optical activity at their characteristic absorption bands attributed to electronic transitions are rare. Our group has reported several work in the field as follows. All of them, including of TiO2 nanotubes, CuO nanoflowers, chiral carbonaceous nanotubes, N-doped chiral carbon nanotubes et al exhibited optical response to circularly polarized light and their antipodal materials showed the mirror-imaged circular dichroism (CD) signals, which could be attributed to the electronic transitions from the lower energy to a higher energy under a dissymmetric electric field."